# How to forward data from a host computer to a Docker container?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, docker

I am working on a project which uses Docker containers. Docker is installed on a Windows 10 host machine. The aim of the project is to forward the data packets that are received on the host to the docker containers so that the container functions make use of those data packets and in turn forward them to other linked containers.

For eg, consider there are 2 containers(container 1 and container 2) running some arbitrary functions. The following has to be achieved:

```
   Host(Windows 10)----->Container 1------->Container 2------->Host
```

where ------> represents packet forwarding(after the container functions work on them)

As of now, packets are received using Wireshark in the host which just receives the packet and displays the packet details. How can these received packets forwarded to the Docker containers from the host, and from one container to other? Can it be done using Scapy(host to container)? I know that container networking can be used to link different containers,but can data packets be forwarded between them?

Also, by any chance could python or java socket programming be used in the host and inside the containers in any of the context above? Could libraries such as libpcap be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create a network bridge so that your docker containers appear on the host computer's network.

Comment: could you be more specific,such as how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -p argument while running the docker. Example:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080 ubuntu
```

More details:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: this just maps port 8080 of the container to port 80 of the localhost.. what i asked was how the packets can be forwarded from the host to the container

Comment: As far as I know, if both the container and the host listen to the same port, then both will receive the packet. If you want to forward a request after processing, just use a different port on container and call localhost:<container_port> from host after processing the packet.

Comment: i am new to docker and networking and i do not exactly follow what you mean. can you explain with an example how this could be achieved? also by host i mean my physical machine, not the virtual machine on which docker is running

Comment: In normal terminology, the host machine is the one on which docker container will run. So, I am assuming that by physical machine, you mean the same machine on which your docker container is also running.
Lets say you have 2 REST servers, s1 on the machine on which the container is running and s2 running on a docker container. Lets say both s1 & s2 listen on port 8080, and port 8081 of the host is mapped to port 8080 of container. Then, s1 will receive any incoming requests, process them and then call localhost:8081 to let s2 process further. Or maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: ok i now understood your suggestion. Will try it out and let know if it worked or not. But as far as i know, -p command maps container port to the host port and not the vice versa. So whatever running on the container will be exposed to the host and not the reverse, where as i want the reverse to happen (ie) host to container packet forwarding

Answer (score 0):

When you run a container, it will use `bridge` networking by default.

If you want the container to use the hosts interface, you can start the container using `host` networking.

```
docker run network=host ...
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Comment: but how can the data packets captured by the host computer from the internet/any other network be forwarded to the containers?

Comment: When you use `network=host` the container uses your hosts network interface, then you can capture packets directly from within the container. Wireshark can not forward packets, though you can log all traffic to a file and mount that file into your container. If you want to forward packets into your container, use bridge networking, and use something like tcpdump and netcat.